# How to handle scroll view for chat application in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, uiscrollview, scrollview, chat

I am creating one chat application and I am getting a problem with chat scroll. like I've 50 messages then yes I need to scroll down to see the latest message when first open that screen I need that my screen open from the last message (means last message I've sent or I've received).

So basically right now I've done like open the page and inside init state I am calling scroll controller and then going to the end of the scroll and actually it's not working well.

also when I send the message it needs to automatically scroll to the end i've added scroll to end but it's not working like it's scroll until only the second last message it's not scrolling until the last message.

Here is the code that I've tried:

```
   _scrollController.animateTo(
                    _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent,
                    curve: Curves.easeOut,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
                  );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try adding PostFrameCallback:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
  _scrollController.jumpTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent);
});
```

Whenever there is a rebuild, it shows the bottom of the list

Comment: where i need to use this one 
can you tell me exact place

Comment: @RutvikGumasana It can be called inside initState of your Widget

Answer (score 3):

I faced similar challenge while working with chat application and the solution I found for this is below:

```
Align(
    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemCount: 100,
      reverse: true,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, i) {
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(i.toString()),
        );
      },
    ),
  )
```

Keep in mind you have to pass your message array to `ListView.builder` in such a way so that your recent message should be always in the 0th position of the array. you can achieve it by using a query.

Comment: so you mean i need to add reverse list?

Comment: Yes you can sort them by date